# Relationship between .iml file and pom.xml file

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Each time I create a Maven project, there is a `.iml` file along with a `pom.xml` file.
What exactly is their relationship?

Comment: IML is a module file created by IntelliJ IDEA. It stores information about a development module, saves the module paths, dependencies, and other settings.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The pom.xml is used by maven to resolve your project's dependencies, which plugins to execute and a lot of other things. From the [maven website](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html):

> A Project Object Model or POM is the fundamental unit of work in Maven. It is an XML file that contains information about the project and configuration details used by Maven to build the project.

The `.iml` file on the other hand is part of IntelliJ's own [project structure](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/project_structure.html#project-and-its-components). The short version is that it declares the libraries (e.g. jars) that are visible only to the module, and not the rest of the project or other projects. It's an xml file containing a library entry for each artifact declared in your `pom.xml`, along with its scope (e.g. `TEST` or `COMPILE`). For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_8">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/test-classes" />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="COMPILE" name="Maven: com.google.guava:guava:18.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: junit:junit:4.12" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

I assume IntelliJ keeps its own file format so it can read the project faster, regardless of which build system the project is using (e.g. *maven* vs. *gradle*).

Comment: What is the proper way to add a file to the current Maven project? I tried to add a file by right clik "new-> file", but next time I open the project, it disappeared.

Comment: I usually do this in IntelliJ's [Project tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tool-windows.html), right click on the desired folder (or Java package) and select `New`->`Java class` or whatever file type I want to add.

Comment: IMHO the fact IntelliJ uses its own format is the cause of more frustration than any startup time. Consider switching branches in the console. I spend about 10 minutes fighting with intellij trying to get it to determine the new versions whereas I find NetBeans just picks them up immediately.

Answer (score 13):

IntelliJ idea doesn't understand the [maven project mode](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#What_is_a_POM)l (POM.xml) itself. When creating or importing maven project in idea. It also creating its own project structure, maven dependencies , module details etc etc.. basically required project metadata in the format it can understand and use it internally for it actions. These metadata stored in `.iml` file and `.idea` project directory.

Main advantage of keeping it's own structure would provide capacity to run faster and manage project efficiently.  I hope this give some explanation on the relationship between these two files.

**Sample pom.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
            <version>${jmock.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${jmock.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junitperf</groupId>
            <artifactId>junitperf</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <jmock.version>2.5.1</jmock.version>
        <junit.version>4.6</junit.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.14</log4j.version>
        <org.slf4j.version>1.5.2</org.slf4j.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**Relavent IDEA .iml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_8">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/test-classes" />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: log4j:log4j:1.2.14" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.5.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.easymock:easymock:2.5.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.jmock:jmock:2.5.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.jmock:jmock-junit4:2.5.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: junit:junit-dep:4.4" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: junit:junit:4.6" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: junitperf:junitperf:1.8" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: So When you add a file in iml, how to pass that to pom.xml ?

Comment: @alcoforado,
Idea works in another way: it use one-way sync from pom to *iml but not vice-versa. So add your dependency to pom and reimport this pom (in Meven toolwindow) - record will be automatically added to iml. .
  But it seems  idea does not remove old entries from iml (when you removed them from pom). So to make 'full' sync:
  1. Open Project Structure-> Modules -> dependencies, remove all Maven entries. 2. Close window, Maven >  clean then reimport maven project. Then Main menu -> Build-> rebuild project.

Answer (score 1):

The `.iml` file is generated using the pom.xml.

When you open a project in IntelliJ for the first time, IntelliJ downloads all the required dependencies using the `pom.xml` as reference. There is a one-way sync between the `pom.xml` and the `.iml` file.

When you try to run the project, the `.iml` file and `.idea` directory are created. These files and directories allow IntelliJ to run faster.