# Explanation of new Spring project file structure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and using their [REST tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/), I noticed that a bunch of files were created for me to start with. However I don't see any explanation in their tutorials as to what these files do, specifically:

- spring-rest.iml
- mvnw.cmd
- mvnw
- empty application.properties file

What do these files do? Will I be touching them in the course of my Spring development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `*.iml` files are IntellJs own project structure files. Have a read here for details: [Relationship between .iml file and pom.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879675/relationship-between-iml-file-and-pom-xml-file)
- `mvnw.cmd` & `mvnw` are part of the [maven-wrapper](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-wrapper). It's there that you don't have to install versions of maven on your OS.

> - mvnw: it's an executable Unix shell script used in place of a fully installed Maven
> - mvnw.cmd: it's the Batch version of the above script
> - mvn: the hidden folder that holds the Maven Wrapper Java library and its properties file

- properties files are there to [configure your application](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) per environment easily. Also, you can set up a lot of spring configuration there. You will touch it therefore!

Comment: Thanks! this is the explanation I was looking for